# Sticky header footer, Need for scrollable content (horizontal + vertical)

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is the layout that I have been trying to get:

Fixed header [has 150px height]
 => Inside the header it has two text boxes of 60px width at the far right end (one below the other).

Content in between header and footer can scroll.

Sticky footer [has 50px in height]

So, the problem I am running into is when I minimize the screen, there is no right scrolling that is enabled. So I am not able to enter in the text box on the right side of the header.

=> If it set overflow-x:scroll, the right scrolling gets enabled, but every div gets a scrollbar, which makes the page look bad.

Can someone help me a clean way to do this ?

The code I have is:

```
#Header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; 
  left: 0px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%; 
}

// Spacing for the text box in right side, inside the header
#Right spacing {
  position: relative;
  left: 70%;
  height: 100%;
}

// Input box of 60px width
.input {
   width: 60px;
   margin-top: 6px;
   border: 1px solid #999;
   padding: 10px;
   color: #999;
}

// Right spaced content in between header and footer
#Content {
   margin: 0px 40px 0px auto;
   min-height: 100%
   position: absolute;
   padding-top: 150px;
   width: 300px;
   right: 60px;
   height: 100%;
}

#Footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px; 
  height: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you try adding a `min-width` to the header? That might keep the page scrolling at some point.

Comment: Can you add you html markup?

Comment: Pinching and zooming will not always reset the width to 100% of the current zoom. You mad need to use some js on a `.resize()` trigger. Also, you should really use @media queries for responsive design. Liquid design (Percentages) don't always bode well with sticky headers/footers.

Comment: Is this what you're looking after? http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/2V3P2/

Comment: @Hashem Qolami That code also has the same problem. When I try to increase the size of the textbox and try to resize, I dont see horizantal scrolls coming for the page.

Comment: @VIDesignz Thanks for the input. Is there some example code where I can look up to understand it better ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple script that when the window is resized, you can use that as a trigger to change properties of elements, such as header width, div widths and so on..

```
window.onresize = function(event) {

    var newWidth = $(window).width();
    $('#header').css({'width': newWidth });

}
```

Comment: @user2231191 My answer was not a solution "as is"..it was more of a technique. I just don't quite get what your issue/goal is so its hard for me to come up with a solution for you.